# Android webview finds inexistent syntax errors in javascript files

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-webview

I have this code in a single activity Android app:

```
        final WebView wvBrowser = this.findViewById( R.id.wvBrowser );

        WebSettings webSettings = wvBrowser.getSettings();

        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls( true );
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled( true );
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls( true );
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls( false );
        webSettings.setSupportZoom( true );
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName( "utf-8" );

        // Prevent opening the default browser on link click.
        wvBrowser.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient() );

        // Loads the HTML file from the assets folder.
        //wvBrowser.loadUrl( "file:///android_asset/index.html" );
        String htmlSrc = "<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('file:///android_asset/index.html')</script></head><body></body></html>";
        wvBrowser.loadDataWithBaseURL( "file:///android_asset/", htmlSrc, "text/html", "UTF-8",null );
```

The HTML file I'm loading has the following in its HEAD section:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="verbs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="montecristo.js"></script>
    <title>Montecristo</title>
    <link href="fijs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This code is available in the [GitHub for the text game Montecristo](https://github.com/baltasarq/Montecristo), and also in the [GitHub repository for the text games engine, fi.js](https://github.com/baltasarq/fi-js).

I only receive this feedback:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(7)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =", source: file:///android_asset/fi.js (7)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: actions is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/verbs.js (8)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: ctrl is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/montecristo.js (5)
```

Everything works fine in Firefox or Chromium, but it weirdly seems to be broken for Android's web view. I've tried `loadDataBaseURL()`, to no avail.

Comment: Could you share the JS code to rule it out?

Comment: `setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);`

Comment: @Kobe, the code for fi.js and verbs.js is here: https://github.com/baltasarq/fi-js

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya, I tried that, but no luck.

Comment: I've just tried with cordova, and it works.

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya, nope, no luck.